# C# Inheritance and accessing data stored in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, .net, inheritance, web

I'm having trouble figuring out how to retrieve data from SQL and store into the appropriate subtype. For example, I have an inventory system.  I have a base class called "Assets" and I have the following subclasses which extend from "Assets":
1. Laptop (has speed and memory fields)
2. MobileDevice (has esn and PIN fields)

Each subclass has its own unique fields (as shown above) and they share common fields (i.e. make, model, serial no. etc...). My question is, if someone performs a search of all assets for a particular user via a webpage, the resultset would include any number of these different types. If I click on "view details" for an iPhone, how do I tell the page to load a MobileDevice vs. Laptop.  Right now, I am only able to pull results as an Asset, but then I'm missing those unique fields. Is this even possible? I cant seem to find anything on the web. is it just a matter of casting? Please help!  Please note: I'm using C#, but no LINQ. Just stored procedures etc...  Appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post your C# code otherwise any answers will be based on a bunch of probably wrong assumptions (and more details about how it talks to the web - a sample response would be great too).

_Presumably_ your web service responds with something like JSON, and presumably your JSON contains something that identifies those JSON objects as a mobile or laptop. Then it's just a case of looping through that JSON and map each one to a `Laptop` or `MobileDevice` C# object, all stored in e.g. an `Asset[]` or `List<Asset>`.

Comment: It's more a general question. No code yet as I'm trying to figure out the best way to tackle this.

Comment: We expect a specific question on SO. Maybe you can do some prototype design then ask the difficulty you face during the progress.

Comment: Have you looked at MongoDB (or another NoSQL database). They are particularly suited to storing this type of data. I would also be looking at hibernate (nHibernate) to do some of the ORM work for you. Might all be a steep learning curve but that's part of the fun!

Comment: Thanks for the response. unfortunately (I neglected to mention), SQL server is my only option with regard to DB.

Answer (score 0):

First, the basic problem is the mismatch between relational and object oriented design.  This is something that doesn't appear to be that big of a problem until you start looking at it.  The first thing to note is that an idea relational design and an ideal OO design are different because they are set up around different concerns.  Relational design focuses on functional dependencies in the mathematical sense (f(x) = y) while OO design focuses on encapsulating state behind interface.  The different goals are what creates this problem in the first place.

So the first thing to do is to realize that your question assumes a design coupling that should not exist.  So on to how I would try to solve the problem.

You start out with an inheritance tree in your application like so:

- Supertype

  - Subtype 1
  - Subtype 2
  - Subtype 3

In a database environment you will have the supertype's data be represented by a subset of columns from one or more tables.  The subtypes will have 0 or more additional fields from these or other tables.

You basically have a few ways of solving this problem.

1. Many ORMs have functions for handling these sorts of issues for you, or
2. You attach the mapping to the subtype, and fully override that of the supertype.

If you are already using an ORM, solving it there is the best approach.  If you are writing SQL by hand somewhere, then usually the second method is cleaner (and among other things allows for better polymorphism, so you can get better OO and better relational design).

Comment: But what is the best way of retrieving that data into the appropriate object. For example. If its a mobile device, how I do tell it select data and store it into the MobileDevice object vs., Asset? Is it just a matter of casting?

Comment: I think you want to separate your persistence assumptions from your business object behavior.  A DAO/Repository pattern might be  good option here.  Then the persistence layer gets to know what subtype to return and returns it.  The upper level then just gets to care about interface and behavior.

Comment: one thing I was playing with is the following code:  could I do something like this when retrieving data from SQL?. Assume the value 1 = mobile device:                         if (Convert.ToInt16(rd["assetType"]) == 1){ Asset = new MobileDevice(); }